# problemas al redireccionar luego del login

Tags: php, javascript, login

saludos y gracias por su tiempo.
estoy enviando un forData con fetch. el problema es que para que me funcione el login tengo que manualmente que recargar la pagina. lo intente con Location de php. y con el location.href de js.
este es mi codigo de php

```html
$query2->execute(['username' => $username, 'password' => md5($password)]);
    
                $row = $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


                if($row){//pass valido
                        
                        echo 2; 
                    switch($rol){     
                        $rol = $row['rol_id'];

                            case 1:
                              echo "admin";
                            header("Location: ./../../user/admin/admin.php");
                               
                            break;
            
                            case 2:
                                header('Location: ./../../user/user/user.php');
                                echo "user";
                                
                            break;
                            
                               
                            default:
                        }
```

y este es mi js, donde intento recibir los datos

```html
fetch('/auth/user.php',{
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData,
         
        })  
            .then((response) => response.json())
            
            .then((data) =>{
                console.log('data = ', data);
                console.log('mi response = ', data);
                  
               if(data == "12admin"){
                    alert('hey que onda')
                   
                   errorPassSpan.innerHTML = "";
               }
```

nunca se me ejecuta este IF. aun cuando en consola si recibo "12admin".

Comment: ¿Esas rutas son correctas, no pueden cambiar dependiendo de la página en la que estás? Por otra parte, sería mejor que devuelvas un solo resultado, en lugar de varios `echo` que, supongo, los estás usando a manera de depuración.

Comment: No entiendo. En PHP tienes `case` sin usar `switch` ¿? Luego, si haces un `fetch` desde JS no deberías redirigir desde el servidor. Mejor recibe la respuesta en el `fetch` y redirige desde el cliente. En tu código no veo de dónde saldría el `12admin` que dices que recibes en el `fetch`. A veces, si no limpias los datos, tienes que aplicar luego un `trim` en JS, porque a la respuesta se le pueden pegar espacios en blanco, saltos de línea y cosas así que luego te rompen la comparación.

Comment: saldudos Tryby. si es correcto, lo estoy haciendo a manera de depuracion. lo que estoy haciendo es, primero al momento del usuario agregar el correo, enviar los datos por formData. y luego que el correo es valido, entonces realizo un segundo formData con la data restante. no se si estoy en lo correcto, pero de otra forma no sabria como depuralo.

Comment: saludos  A. Cedano. como le mencione a Tryby, el **1** significa que el correo esta en la base de datos y el **2*** significa que el password es correcto. El switch al parecer lo elimine en la ediccion.

Comment: ya lo solucione amigos. hice lo que Tryby me menciono solo el uso de varios echo. solo deje dos, uno para el pass y otro para el email. con la restpuesta 12 en consola, redireccione desde el cliente y listo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya lo solucione amigos. hice lo que Tryby me menciono solo el uso de varios echo. solo deje dos, uno para el pass y otro para el email. con la restpuesta 12 en consola, redireccione desde el cliente y listo. –

```html
  if(data == 14){
                   
                    errorPassSpan.innerHTML = "Agregar Credenciales Validas";                   
               }
               if(data == 12){
                   
                   errorPassSpan.innerHTML = "";
                   location.href ="./../../user/admin/admin.php";
               }
```